# Set timeout in Opensearch search method gives error

Tags: python, opensearch

I'm using Opensearch-py to handle interaction with an OpenSearch. However I'm having some issues with setting a timeout to fix a timeout issue when searching an index.

```
self.get_client().search(
        index=index,
        body=search_body,
        scroll=scroll,
        ignore=ignore,
        size=size,
        timeout=30)
```

The error I'm getting:

> ValueError: Timeout value connect was 30.0, but it must be an int, float or None.

I have a hard time understanding why 30 isn't resolved to an int. I've also tried "30", "30s", 30.0 and casting using int() and float(). Same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/opensearchpy/connection/http_requests.py", line 179, in perform_request
    response = self.session.send(prepared_request, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/requests/adapters.py", line 426, in send
    timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)
  File "/usr/src/app/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 94, in __init__
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, 'connect')
  File "/usr/src/app/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 135, in _validate_timeout
    raise ValueError("Timeout value %s was %s, but it must be an "
ValueError: Timeout value connect was 30.0, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Comment: What happens if you change `timeout=30` to `timeout=None`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [document](https://opensearch-project.github.io/opensearch-py/_modules/opensearchpy/client.html#OpenSearch.search)
, params is a “dictionary” of query parameters. So, the following implementation will work.

```
search(
 index=index,
       body=search_body,
       params={
         "timeout":30, 
         "scroll": scroll, 
         "ignore": ignore, 
         "size": size
       }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

had the same issue. Didn't fix it directly, but found a workaround: you can pass the timeout parameter in the OpenSearch constructor.